# how to use torchaudio with torch xla on google colab tpu

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, tpu

I'm trying to run a pytorch script which is using torchaudio on a google TPU. To do this I'm using [pytorch xla](https://github.com/pytorch/xla) following [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/xla/blob/master/contrib/colab/style_transfer_inference-xrt-1-15.ipynb#scrollTo=j1w1G4AcWw9f), more specifically I'm using this code cell to load the xla:

```
!pip install torchaudio
import os
assert os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'], 'Make sure to select TPU from Edit > Notebook settings > Hardware accelerator'

VERSION = "20200220"  #@param ["20200220","nightly", "xrt==1.15.0"]
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/xla/master/contrib/scripts/env-setup.py -o pytorch-xla-env-setup.py
!python pytorch-xla-env-setup.py --version $VERSION

import torch

import torchaudio

import torch_xla
```

however this is incompatible with the version of torchaudio that I need as: `ERROR: torchaudio 0.4.0 has requirement torch==1.4.0, but you'll have torch 1.5.0a0+e95282a which is incompatible.`

I couldn't find anywhere how to load `torch 1.4.0` using pytorch xla.

I tried to use the nightly version of torch audio but that gives the error as follows:

```
!pip install torchaudio_nightly -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/torch_nightly.html

import os
assert os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'], 'Make sure to select TPU from Edit > Notebook settings > Hardware accelerator'

VERSION = "20200220"  #@param ["20200220","nightly", "xrt==1.15.0"]
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/xla/master/contrib/scripts/env-setup.py -o pytorch-xla-env-setup.py
!python pytorch-xla-env-setup.py --version $VERSION

import torch
import torchaudio

import torch_xla
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-968e9d93c06f> in <module>()
      9 
     10 import torch
---> 11 import torchaudio
     12 
     13 import torch_xla

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchaudio/__init__.py in <module>()
      3 
      4 import torch
----> 5 import _torch_sox
      6 
      7 from .version import __version__, git_version

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/_torch_sox.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6caffe26detail37_typeMetaDataInstance_preallocated_29E

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So how would I go to load the stable version or 1.4.0 version of pytorch using xla or is there any other workaround for this situation?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hello. What type of TPU have you created? Also what TPU software version?

Comment: The notebook link is stale trowing a 404.I tested with this notebook.https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/pytorch/xla/blob/master/contrib/colab/getting-started.ipynb#scrollTo=sPJVqAKyml5W.I am going to post an Answer below if this does not work for you let me know and I'll keep testing some more.Maybe you could also check the link to you note book.When I first the notebook above I also received the same error "ERROR: torchaudio 0.4.0 has requirement torch==1.4.0,but you'll have torch 1.5.0a0+e95282a which is incompatible.but with some changes all cells in the notebook completed successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested using the notebook below;
[Getting Started with PyTorch on Cloud TPUs](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/pytorch/xla/blob/master/contrib/colab/getting-started.ipynb)

After changing the cell containing;

FROM:

```
    VERSION = "20200325"  #@param ["1.5" , "20200325", "nightly"]
    !curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/xla/master/contrib/scripts/env-setup.py -o pytorch-xla-env-setup.py
    !python pytorch-xla-env-setup.py --version $VERSION
```

TO:

```
    VERSION = "20200325"  #@param ["1.5" , "20200325", "nightly"]
    !curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/xla/master/contrib/scripts/env-setup.py -o pytorch-xla-env-setup.py
    !pip install torchvision
    !pip install torch==1.4.0
    !pip install torchaudio==0.4.0
    %matplotlib inline
    !python pytorch-xla-env-setup.py --version $VERSION
```

All cells ran successfully, and the import statements below threw no errors;

```
    # imports pytorch
      import torch

    # imports the torch_xla package
      import torch_xla
      import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip uninstall torch -y
!pip install torch==1.6
```

if it appearslike..  "WARNING:root:TPU has started up successfully with version pytorch-1.6"

enjoy...!!